# Foursquare Can't Geocode full address?

Tags: geocoding, foursquare, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to input a full address "700 flower street, los angeles, CA" but its giving error

```
[meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 400
            [errorType] => failed_geocode
            [errorDetail] => Couldn't geocode param near: 700 flower street, los angeles, CA
        )
```

Does anyone know why? Does Foursquare not provide such a service? They work on very simple stuff, like "los angeles". Why does it not do full address? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 400 usually means "Bad input" -- double-check what your're sending to Foursquare to make sure it's valid and it's what their API is expecting.

Incidentally, I work at SmartyStreets. We are able to geocode that address:

http://smartystreets.com/?street=700%20flower%20street,%20los%20angeles,%20CA

And even *more* incidentally, Foursquare just signed up with us not too long ago. Not sure if it was for internal purposes or if it was for some aspect of their service, but I guess we'll see...

(By the way, did you know that address is missing a suite or apartment number?)

Comment: SmartyStreets can return approximate coordinates for any address the USPS recognizes.